# R Shiny Custom User Filter with Checkboxes

Tags: r, shiny

I have data table output that I want users to be able to create their own custom table by using checkboxes to select which row/element they want.  In the example below is a mtcars output.  For example I want users to be able to pick say A Mazda, Fiat, Toyota, and a Dodge model using a check box.  As far as trying any code, I haven't found any examples that come close.

```r
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
    
    # basic example
    shinyApp(
        ui = fluidPage(
            selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                        c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                          "Transmission" = "am",
                          "Gears" = "gear"), multiple = T),
            tableOutput("data")
        ),
     server = function(input, output) {
            output$data <- renderTable({
                mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
            }, rownames = TRUE)
        }
    )
    
}
```

Comment: This works very well, just one question, the rownames i.e. the choices show as separate table or above the output, is there a way to do this within the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach below is 1) create a checkbox group input listing the car names (i.e. rownames) as the names, having the corresponding values be the row numbers and 2) using those row numbers to filter your data.frame on the server.

Using the reactive `rowsToUse` will update every time the selection changes. It also allows the handling of the case when no rows are selecting (default to all rows in the example below).

```
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "variable", 
      label = "Cars:",
      choiceNames = rownames(mtcars),
      choiceValues = seq(NROW(mtcars))
    ),
    tableOutput("data")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    
    rowsToUse <- reactive(
      
      if(is.null(input$variable)) {
        seq(NROW(mtcars)) 
      } else{ 
        as.numeric(input$variable)
      }
      
    )
    
    output$data <- renderTable({
      
      mtcars[rowsToUse(),  , drop = FALSE]
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  }

)
```

Comment: This works very well, just one question, the rownames i.e. the choices show as separate table or above the output, is there a way to do this within the same table?

Comment: There are many table building packages out there that allow you to select rows and provide a reactive input on which you could filter your other table. `gt`, along with being a option itself, has a list of options: https://gt.rstudio.com/#how-gt-fits-in-with-other-packages-that-generate-display-tables.

If you're set on having an inline checkbox, may of those allow HTML in the table. `reactable` has built in check box for selection: https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#select-on-click